# How to process a signal in frequency domain then convert it bakc to time domain?

Tags: fft, fourier-transform, sampling, frequency-response, ifft

Maybe a example of coupling effect in frequency modulated continuous (FMCW) radar will be helpful to better demonstrate my problem.

Let us consider a FMCW radar system. We have a complex transmitted signal $\textbf{x}(t)$ with bandwidth $B=50 \, \textbf{MHz}$, and duration time $T=7.3 \, \mu s$ of a chirp and $N=1024$ snapshots for a chirp, which leads to around $140 \textbf{MHz}$ sampling frequency, where $f_s=N/T=1024/(7.3*10^{-6})\approx 140 \textbf{MHz}$. For the considered bandwidth, we have simulated a coupling coefficient at $1 \, \textbf{MHz}$ interval. Then we want to model the time domain coupling signal at the receiver with considering those frequency response from ANSYS HFSS at $1 \, \textbf{MHz}$ interval within the bandwidth. How should we achieve it?

---

Suppose we have a complex linear frequency modulated signal $\textbf{x}(t)$ with bandwidth $B$ and duration time $T$. We sample this signal with sampling rate $f_s\gt B$, then we have the sampled version of this signal $\textbf{x}(n)\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N}$, where $N$ is the number of snapshots.

Then if for $M\,(M\lt N)$ different considered frequencies within the bandwidth, we have a frequency dependent effect on $\textbf{x}$, which is
$$\textbf{y}_m=H(m)\textbf{x}_m,\, m=1,\cdots, M $$
where $H(m)$ is the coefficient for the effect on that frequency. So how to peroform this frequency-depent effect on $M$ considered frequencies, then achieve the corresponding time domain signal after this frequency-dependent effect?

Comment: you already tag with [tag:fft] and [tag:ifft], so I'll presume you're familiar with the DFT — as long as your frequencies divide $B$, that's the solution right there.

Comment: Also, your example on top is in **direct** contradiction to your question below: Question says $f_s =B$, the example says $f_s \gg B$; so, which is it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sorry for not modifying the question below. I have now srt $f_s \gt B$.

Comment: Please clarify by editing, not in comments. Also, it's not clear to me how you arrived at 139 MHz as sampling rate, that does not arise from your requirements. Please edit your question to clarify that, as well.

Comment: OK, I will edit to clarify.

Comment: For your first comment, yes, I know that I should exploit fft to achieve the frequency domain signal of $\mathbf{x}(n)$, then multipllies the frequency response of $50 \, \textbf{MHz}$ with $1 \, \textbf{MHz}$ interval, and finally convert it back time domain. But, for like $f_s = 140\, \textbf{MHz} $,  the frequency samples of FFT might not coincide with the samples of frequency response with $1 \, \textbf{MHz}$ interval for the bandwidth. So I am wondering how to handle this.

Comment: typically, either by zero-padding in time domain to achieve a size of FFT where your frequencies of interest end up on divisors, or by interpolating the frequency response data so make it fit the discrete frequencies. What you want depends on the purpose you're doing this for – which you sadly don't speak about!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144777/discussion-between-tyrela-and-marcus-muller).

Answer (score -2):

This is what a basic AM,FM or PM radio does.Here is the process diagram:

[image]

It takes a signal in the time domain x(t) discretizes it and return its frequency response which creates the baseband signal for the input of the modulator.The baseband signal isnt ready for transmission it is very lossy so the modulator raises its frequency and makes it a bandpass signal at some centered frequency $f_{c}$.Then it can be transmitted.The demodulator takes the received signal , creates the baseband out of it and sends it for signal processing.During signal processing the discrete time signal ,which is encoded in the demodulated baseband signal is extracted and the receiver can finally hear the music...

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question, though!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as Marcus pointed out, this doesn't seem to address my problem.